# Counting distinct IDs for each date in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I have a dataset and I want to create a column(not measure) to calculate the count of customers in each month. I don't know how I can count each customer once a month in Power BI.

I wrote this code but it counts the number of frequent customers more than once a month.

```
myCol = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT('table'[user_id] ) , 'table'[order_date] )
```

For example, it's my data:

[image: 1]

The true result should be:

[image: 2]

but my code returns this result:

[image: 3]

How should I write the code for this calculating column to get a true result?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to calculate per month, you need a "year_month" column.

Then:

```
count_of_customer = 
CALCULATE( 
   DISTINCTCOUNT('table'[user_id]), 
   ALLEXCEPT('table', 'table'[year_month])
)
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit:**

You don't need a calculated column, you need a measure:

```
count_of_customer =
    COUNTROWS (
       SUMMARIZE ( 'table', 'table'[year_month], 'table'[user_id])
    )
```

Comment: the result of your code exactly is the same as the result of my code and returns false answers. @RADO

Comment: I am getting a sense that there might be a confusion about the results you expect. You said that the result must be a calculated column, not a measure. But the image in your question shows a summary report which would require a measure, not a calculated column. How did you produce your current output report?

Comment: It's the table visual of power bi. @RADO

Comment: @WhoIsKi - I posted an edit.

Comment: I agree with you. My question is confusing. This question was part of the solution that came to my mind for my problem. I wrote the whole question in another post and I am deleting this confusing post. Please check this link. @RADO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69219947/calculating-the-cumulative-values-in-power-bi