# Calculating the cumulative values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, etl, cumulative-sum, measure

I have two tables:

- user table (contains: user registration data. columns: user_id, create_date)
- customer order table (contains: history of orders. columns: user_id, order_date, order_id)

*user and customer aren't the same. when a user registers his first order, he becomes a customer.

For each month of each year, I want the accumulative count of distinct users and the accumulative count of the distinct customers because at last, I want to calculate the ratio of *the accumulative count of the distinct customers* to *the accumulative count of the distinct users* for each month.

I don't know how can I calculate the accumulative values and the Ratio that I said, using **DAX**.

Note that if a customer registers more than one order in a month, I want to count him just once for that month and if he registers a new order in the next months, also I count him in each new month.

Maybe these pictures help you to understand my question better.

-I don't count_of_users and count_of_customers columns in my tables. I should calculate them.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

the *user* table:

| user_id | create_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-12-03 |
| 2 | 2018-01-01 |
| 3 | 2018-01-01 |
| 4 | 2018-02-04 |
| 5 | 2018-03-10 |
| 6 | 2018-04-07 |
| 7 | 2018-04-08 |
| 8 | 2018-09-12 |
| 9 | 2018-10-02 |
| 10 | 2018-10-02 |
| 11 | 2018-10-09 |
| 12 | 2018-10-11 |
| 13 | 2018-10-12 |
| 14 | 2018-10-12 |
| 15 | 2018-10-20 |

the *customer order* table:

| user_id | order_date | order_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-03-28 | 120 |
| 1 | 2018-03-28 | 514 |
| 1 | 2018-03-30 | 426 |
| 2 | 2018-02-11 | 125 |
| 2 | 2018-03-01 | 547 |
| 3 | 2018-02-10 | 588 |
| 3 | 2018-04-03 | 111 |
| 4 | 2018-02-10 | 697 |
| 5 | 2018-04-02 | 403 |
| 5 | 2018-04-05 | 321 |
| 6 | 2018-04-09 | 909 |
| 11 | 2018-10-25 | 8401 |

Comment: Please add data samples (as text) for both tables

Comment: I added both tables. @RADO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few building blocks for this. Here is the data model I used:

[image]

**<edit>**
I see user_id in the different tables are not the same, in that case you can omit the relationship between the tables and the two relationships from the `Calendar` table will both be active - with no need to change the relationship semantics in the `count_of_customer` measure. **</edit>**

The calendar table is important because we can't rely on one single date column to aggregate data from different tables, so we create a common calendar table with this sample DAX code:

```
Calendar = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDARAUTO () ,
    "Year" , YEAR ( [Date] ) ,
    "Month" , FORMAT ( [Date] , "MMM" ) ,
    "Month-Year" , FORMAT ( [Date] , "MMM")&"-"&YEAR ( [Date] ) ,
    "YearMonthNo" , YEAR ( [Date] ) * 12 + MONTH ( [Date] ) - 1
)
```

Make sure to sort the `Month-Year` column by the `YearMonthNo` column so your tables look nice:

[image]

Set your relationships as shown with the active relationship from `Calendar` to `user` - if not the measures will not work unless you alter the relationships accordingly in the code! In my data model the inactive relationship is between `Calendar` and `customer order`.

Next up are the measures we will use for this. First off we count the users, a simple row count:

```
count_of_users = COUNTROWS ( user )
```

Then we count distinct user ids in the order table to count customers, here we need to use the *inactive* relationship between `Calendar` and `customer order` and to do this we have to invoke `CALCULATE`:

```
count_of_customers = 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'customer order'[user_id] ) ,
    USERELATIONSHIP (
        'Calendar'[Date] ,
        'customer order'[order_date]
    )
)
```

We can use this measure to count users cumulatively:

```
cumulative_users = 
VAR _maxVisibleDate = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) 
RETURN
CALCULATE ( 
    [count_of_users] , 
    ALL ( 'Calendar' ) , 
    'Calendar'[Date] <= _maxVisibleDate
)
```

And this measure to count cumulative customers per month:

```
cumulative_customers = 
VAR _maxVisibleDate = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) 
RETURN
CALCULATE ( 
    SUMX ( 
        VALUES ( 'Calendar'[YearMonthNo] ) ,
        [count_of_customers] 
    ),
    ALL ( 'Calendar' ) , 
    'Calendar'[Date] <= _maxVisibleDate
)
```

Lastly we want the ratio of these last cumulative measures:

```
cumulative_customers/users = 
DIVIDE (  
    [cumulative_customers] , 
    [cumulative_users] 
)
```

And here is your result:

[image]

Comment: You said:" user_id in the different tables are not the same". What do you mean? note that, all users aren't a customer. but all the customers are users. @Marcus

Comment: If I use the calendar table, I see errors in my other reports that depend on the date. @Marcus

Comment: Not sure what you expect me to do with your entire report? If you aren’t using a date table already it’s a good time to start.